# Как правильно расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

В работе, также изучена проблема верного истолкования наружной социальной рекламы, социального проекта «Все равно», посвященной проблема ДТП, на территории города Саратова.
или
В работе, также изучена проблема верного истолкования наружной социальной рекламы социального проекта «Все равно», посвященной проблема ДТП на территории города Саратова.

В данном случае уточнения обосабливаются или нет и почему?
или
В данном случае уточнения обосабливаются или нет, и почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...изучена проблема верного
> истолкования...

**?**

По-моему, что-то в этих словах не то... Но если закрыть глаза на это "не то" и на повтор слова **проблема**, предложение можно было бы записать, думаю, так:

*В работе также изучена **проблема** верного истолкования созданной в рамках социального проекта «Все равно»  наружной  рекламы,  посвященной **проблеме** ДТП на территории города Саратова.*

Comment: Слава, а вам не кажется, что определение чересчур оторвано от определяемого слова? Тяжеловатый текст получается. **В работе также изучена проблема верного истолкования - чего? дальше причастие, а затем определение**. Исходный текст, конечно, тоже не лучше. 
Но и ваш текст тяжелый получился.

Answer (score 0):

Корректно: В работе также изучена проблема верного истолкования наружной социальной рекламы, социального проекта ''Все равно'', посвященн***ого*** проблем***е*** ДТП, на территории города Саратова. 
***Запятая закрывает причастный оборот.***

Answer (score 0):

"Проблема верного истолкования"? По смыслу же это абсурдно, словно проблема в том, что реклама будет верно истолкована. Почему же не сказать "проблематика истолкования"? Ведь в такой работе, наверняка, и будут рассматриваться именно сложности восприятия и возможные варианты, что и является общим явлением "проблематикой". Проблемы ДТП это тоже почти тавтология (особенно, если не развернуть идею), разве бывают не проблемные транспортные происшествия? Это как будто кто-то хочет создавать идеальные и беспроблемные ДТП.
Значит, как уже писали "посвященным проблемЕ ДТП" то есть, самому факту существования ДТП. Или же просто посвященный ДТП в городе. Либо, например, с каким-то прилагательным: регулярным/частым/распространенным ДТП.